# Intent service for retrofit call

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-intentservice

I have created an IntentService as follows:

```
      @Override
       protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
               // DB opertaion
                list.addAll(users);
          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
               RestClient.getInstance(this).get().sendReading(list.get(i)).enqueue(this);
            }
           //retrofit callback
        @Override
         public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CommonResponse> call, @NonNull 
          Response<CommonResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getStatusCode() == Constants.SUCCESS_CODE) {
                 //DB insert operation
                }
            }
```

---

In the above code, I'm using realm database and which has multiple records, I take few records and hit API in one by one using retrofit and I am using intent service, when I got a successful result then I update my DB.Here my problem is when I call the intent service. **it hit only one record, but I pass multiple records**.

I'm calling this service from onResume method of an Activity. So whenever the activity resumes this service is called :

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    Intent updateService = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
    startService(UpdateService);

}
```

Comment: `IntentService`  already asynchronous and it will return immediately just after it finishes `onHandleIntent()`. If are doing task in separate thread which RetroFit usually does `IntentService` will not wait for it to complete . You probably need to call api part Synchronously .

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Can you explain how to change API part synchronous. I am the beginner of android. thanks

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests.

Comment: Thank you, Which this tutorial is very useful.

Comment: @SivaKumar you can follow this video to learn synchronous call.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09r0s9dlitE

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I got this tutorial previous comment.